# "ionic start myApp tabs" no crea la aplicación

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework

¿alguien sabe que puedo hacer en este caso? El comando `$ionic start myApp tabs` no me funciona (error abajo) ya probé reinstalando "ionic" y "@ionic/cli", actualizando Node, pero el error continua, gracias.

````
exports.pathExists = pathExists;

TypeError: Cannot set property pathExists of #< Object > which has only a getter

at Object.< anonymous >
(/home/nano/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-fs/dist/index.js:168:20)

at Object.< anonymous >
(/home/nano/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/node.js:3:20)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer un update a la versión de Ionic, utiliza este comando:

```
npm i -g @ionic/cli@6.9.1
```

Luega intenta crear tu aplicación de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Debes actualizar el cli. Puedes hacerlo con el siguiente comando:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```